# Accessing custom model data from another widget when an item in view is clicked

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QListView` that sets a custom `QAbstractListModel` as the model. The model loads data from a database and puts it all in a `QList<QHash<QString, QString> > dataList` data structure. Each `QHash<QString, QString> data` contains stuff like `data["id"]` and `data["name"]`. The `data["name"]` value is passed to the `QListView` via the model's `data()` method. Now what I want to do is access the `QHash<QString, QString>` belonging to the clicked item from another widget when an item is clicked in the `QListView`.

So something like this...

`connect(view, SIGNAL(clicked(...)), someOtherWidget, SLOT(foo(...))`

And in foo() we could do for example...

`void someOtherWidget::foo(const QHash<QString, QString>& customData) { QMessageBox::information(this, "User ID", customData["id"]; }`

And it would display the item's **id** in the message box.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: +1 to Chris, question isn't immediately obvious at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use special role in your data() function.
data() will then return the QHash

```
QVariant yourModel::data( QModelIndex index, int role )
{
    ....
    if( role == myCustomRole )
    {
        return QVariant::fromValue( myData[ index.row ] )
    }
    ....
}
```

Then in your foo function

```
QHashMap<QString, QString> & model = 
    view->model()->data( view->selectedIndex(), myCustomRole )
        .value< QHashMap<QString, QString> >();
```

Answer (score 0):

A QListView class has a handy clicked() signal, that passes QDataIndex for an item that was clicked. Just define a clicked slot and a custom signal for your model:

```
signals:
    void elementSelected (QStringHash _element); // Also, there's a string hash
                                                 // class, so save the <>
public slots:
    void onClicked (const QModelIndex &_index);
```

and create a respective slot for your widget:

```
public slots:
    void onElementSelected (QStringHash _element);
```

In onClicked, emit the elementSelected() signal

```
void YourModel::onClicked (const QModelIndex &_index)
{
    elementSelected (dataList (_index.row())
}
```

Finally, just connect all your signals: clicked() from list view to your model and elementSelected() from your model to your custom widget. If you really need the view to emit elementSelected() signal, and not the model, you'll have to define a class derived from QListView with a similar signal and connect elementSelected() signal from the model to elementSelected() signal from this new class. It's perfectly okay to connect signals to each other.